# Access files in A360 Drive using Data Management API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

I am trying to view files in both a personal A360 account and in my A360 drive. Is this possible using the Forge API?

Comment: This question has been researched. Autodesk uses SO for their support issues which is why this question is so general.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Forge Data Management API to access your file in your A360 personal application, and also some other Autodesk SAAS app including BIM 360 Team, Fusion Team (formerly known as A360 Team), BIM 360 Docs. But AFAIK, currently the API can not access file in A360 drive.

For details, please check the page at https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/developers_guide/overview/